# is it possible to have an unrelated autotools project inside an autotools project directory?

Tags: autotools, subdirectory

I have two autotools projects that work fine on their own:

p1 does not build any libs nor use C++, and is meant to be compiled by the user. So I don't libtoolize nor LT_INIT here.

p2 creates a tiny C++ library that is used only in development, here I have LT_INIT and call libtoolize.

But when I put the p2 directory inside p1, running automake inside the p2 directory will notice that it's in a subdirectory of an autotools project, and I get the error

```
configure.ac:31: required file `../ltmain.sh' not found
```

I tried adding

```
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])
```

to the configure.ac of p2, but then the ac_aux_dir variable in configure gets empty, and I get the error

```
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh /config.sub
```

(the line in configure tries to run `$ax_aux_dir/config.sub`)

Is there a clean way to have an unrelated autotools project inside an autotools project, or should I just give up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out two minutes after asking, how typical. Apparently, configure.ac has to have:

```
AC_INIT(…)
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(…)
```

and not:

```
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])
AC_INIT(…)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(…)
```

like I had (it gives an error message if `AUX_DIR` is after `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`, which led me to believe it had to be after `AC_INIT` too).

Anyway, this works :)

Answer (score 2):

In configure.ac of p1 you can write:

```
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS(p2)
```

This call to [`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Subdirectories.html) will cause p2 to be treated as a sub project of p1, with its own configure.ac etc., with everything "just working automatically" (hopefully). There's also a [complete small example in the autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Subpackages.html)

Comment: when I try this, it seems that running autoreconf/configure in p1 will try to configure p2 (at least it says `configuring in p2\nconfigure: WARNING: no configuration information is in p2`). I don't want p1 to depend on p2 at all.

Comment: If you want them to be complete separate I'd put them in separate directories. If you want them to be related, but optional I'd use the `if test -d "$srcdir/p2"; then` syntax for `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`.